# Spring mvc datatables slow server side processing

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, datatable

I currently testing the server side datatables with 90,000+ rows of data. I noticed in chrome's inspect element(F12) that every time I click next page, it is taking >5seconds to produce the output. I am only drawing 10 rows of data each page.

Here is my code:

```
var dt = $('#mytable').css("width", "100%").dataTable({
                "sDom": '<"top"tr<"toolbar">pi><"clear">',
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sAjaxSource": "/resource/from/controller",
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                sAjaxDataProp: "aaData", 
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"mData": "colA", "sDefaultContent": "", 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData;
                        }},
                    {"mData": "DateB", "sDefaultContent": "", "mRender": function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                                var dateOnly = data.substring(0, 11);
                                return dateOnly;
                            }
                        }, 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            if (sData != null) {
                                var newDate = sData;
                                nTd.title = newDate.substring(0, 11);
                            }
                        }},
                    {"mData": "ColB", "sDefaultContent": "", 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData;
                        }},
                    {"mData": "ColC", "sDefaultContent": "", 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData;
                        }},
                    {"mData": "ColD", "sDefaultContent": "","mRender": function (data) { return data.toFixed(2);}, 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData.toFixed(2);
                        }},
                    {"mData": "ColE", "sDefaultContent": "", 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData;
                        }},
                    {"mData": "DateB", "sDefaultContent": "", 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData;
                        }},
                    {"mData": "ColF", "sDefaultContent": "", 'fnCreatedCell': function (nTd, sData) {
                            nTd.title = sData;
                        }}, {"mData": "id", "sClass": "dpass"}
                ], "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    varA = $();
                    varB = $();
                }

            });
```

What is causing the slow issue??

Comment: If you only draw 10 rows but retrieve all 90000 on each request that isn't very efficient.

Comment: I used **limit 0,10** in my query and my json only returns 10 rows. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Do some more profiling and figure out what is taking so long...